# program keyboard combinations on mac

Tags: macos, macros, keyboard, hotkeys

I would like to have my mac type '|#' whenever I quickly type the keys 'qs'.  There's a program on Windows called AutoHotKey.  I am wondering if there is a mac equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click Language and Text
3. Click the Text tab
4. Add '|#' in the left column and 'qs' in the right.

Make sure the check box at the top is checked.

Comment: I could not get this to work.  Do I have to reboot for it to take effect?  (I think you mixed up the order in #4, but thanks for the attempt.)

Comment: I never have. Unfortunately, the version of the OS I am currently on that sys pref doesn't work at all. :-/

Comment: actually it DID work, but I didn't see it.  one has to move an additional space in order for the substitution to take effect